# bindFromRequest validation null

Tags: java, playframework

I am new to the Java Play Framework and I'm trying to get the authentication to work. So I am following this tutorial: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/JavaGuide4

Here is my code:

```
public static Result authenticate()
{
    Form<Login> loginForm = form(Login.class).bindFromRequest();

    return ok(loginForm.toString());

}


public static class Login
{
    public String email;
    public String password;

    public String validate()
    {
        return "VALIDATE "+email+password;
    }
}
```

In the method autheticate() I can see the submitted values of the form, but the method validate() in the Login class does not see them (the variables are always null).. The output of loginForm.toString() contains:

```
Form(of=class controllers.Application$Login, data={email=asdf@asdf, password=asdf}, value=None, errors={=[ValidationError(,[VALIDATE nullnull],[])]})
```

As you can see, the data is received.. But in the validate method the data suddenly is equal to null. So how do I fix this?

Comment: As far as I understand the guide you should write the `validate` method into `app/controllers/Application.java` and not `Login.java`. The `Login` class is a model class that provides the structure for the form generate. It doesn't know any data and therefore can't validate the input.

Comment: I don't think that that is strictly speaking true, whilst I wouldn't put the logic in the `Login` class you actually can, I just tested it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention how you are calling `validate()` however I think this might do the trick, do something along the lines of:

```
public static Result authenticate() {
    Form<Login> form = form(Login.class).bindFromRequest();

    // handle errors
    if (!form.hasErrors()) {
        Login login = form.get();
        Logger.debug(login.validate());
    } else {
        // bad request
    }
}
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Method validate in your model should return null if you think that validation has passed, otherwise you should return error message text. Then you need to check form if it contains error by "hasGlobalError" method. globalError is filled when validate() method returns String instead of null. But in your case you should use some model field annotations - https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/java/play/data/validation/Constraints.html.

If you want to check if form fails on those - then you use "hasErrors" method.

```
public static class Login {
@Constraints.Email
public String email;
@Constraints.MinLength(value = 6)
public String password;
}
```

Such model will check if provided emails is really email and if password is longer or equal 6 characters.

ps. Do not use toString on template, you should use render()